# Which columns should be indexed and why?

Tags: database, indexing

Given a table with four columns

```
create table user 
(
    id int primary key,
    username varchar(100),
    age int,
    country varchar(100)
);
```

The most frequent query is based on a where clause on username, age and country. For example:

```
select * 
from user 
where username = "Join Smith" and age > 18 and country = "UK"
```

How to build indexes which would be most efficient and why?

What if the query changes to

```
select * 
from user 
where username like "John Smith" and age = 18 and country = "UK"
```

I would use a composite index on all three columns username, age and country. But I cannot tell if this is most efficient for which case. Please help.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Index in following column order country,age 
because in both queries country will be an exact match and if it first column in index it will  filter out the result
add age as 2nd column in index it will perform a exact match or range query

Answer (score 0):

It is always advisible to keep your id(as primary key, usually the left most column) different from usable columns, keeping this edit = False.

Now doing so, I don't think there should be any issue in executing either of the queries above.